# How to get osmdroid to appear in Fragment on Android 4+

Tags: android, fragment, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I'm attempting to build an app that is natively Android API 15 (4.0.3) with an ActionBar Tabbed UI and a ViewFlipper to switch between tabs. What I can't figure out is how to have OpenStreetMaps (osmdroid) load in a Fragment.

Is there any way I can do this without any TabHost or Compatibility Library hacks? A code sample would greatly help, I've been trying to figure this out for days without any luck on Google. Thanks!